# Using pivot table with Eloquent and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is my problem. I have a table called `news` and table called `categories`, also I have a pivot table that connects these two called `news_categories`.
I am trying to fetch last 10 articles from certain category, but obviously pivot table doesn't have timestapms. 
I was reading about hasMany(), belongToMany() but didn't find a good example of how it is done. Any help is appreciated

So far I have done this to News model:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to("Categories")->withPivot('category_id', 'news_id');
}
```

But I have no idea how to select News based on pivot table value of `category_id`

Comment: If this is Laravel 4 then the method should be `belongsToMany` and not `has_many_and_belongs_to` as that is a Laravel 3 method.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read up on the [Laravel 4 Eloquent Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) a bit...

The relationship function is wrong and you don't need to specify the pivot items. The `withTimestamps()` function will automatically manage those on the pivot table for you.

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category')->withTimestamps();
}
```